# Latest Vim on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Why can I not get Vim 8.1 on Cygwin? The latest version I can find is 8.0.1567-1. I found out that patch 8.1.0372 fixes the slow scrolling when 'cursorline' is set.

Comment: I think you have two options: Either you run cygwin's `Setup.exe` and the version you want is available in the package list, then you can install it like this. Or it is not available already and you'll have to build it manually, as you would do on any other UNIX system.

Comment: ask on the cygwin list (or compile your own version)

Comment: FYI: Vim 8.1.1240-1 has been available through the standard installer since early May.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much.